# Gensim word2vec training doesn't callback on batch end

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec

I am interested in placing a callback on the Gensim word2vec model to trigger some function after each batch. Per [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html), it is possible to place a callback on batch end or epoch end. However, as shown in the MVE below, only the epoch callback actually triggers.

To run the sample, let `corpus_filepath` direct to a line separated file of unpunctuated sentences (words in a sentence on given a line should be space separated). You may also need to change `workers` in the `Word2Vec` instantiation.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

corpus_filepath = 'train.txt'
out_filepath = 'out.txt'

class MyCallback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_batch_end(self, model):
        print('batch end')

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        print('epoch end')


callback = MyCallback()
model = Word2Vec(size=300, window=5, min_count=0, workers=64)
print('Making vocabulary...')
model.build_vocab(corpus_file=corpus_filepath)
print('Beginning training...')
model.train(corpus_file=corpus_filepath, epochs=5, total_words=model.corpus_total_words, callbacks=[callback])
```

Incorrect output (missing batch printouts):

```
Making vocabulary...
Beginning training...
epoch end
epoch end
epoch end
epoch end
epoch end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it appears the `on_batch_begin` and `on_batch_end` callbacks have not been implemented by Gensim in the `corpus_file` mode you're using.

Thus, you could try changing to the traditional corpus-iterable mode to see the callbacks fire. (Overall training throughput in that mode tends to max out with around 8-12 workers, no matter how many CPU cores are available.)

However, note also that even there, the per-batch callbacks are run at arbitrary times in multiple threads - so many things are unwise/unsafe to attempt in those callbacks. Attempted saves of the model, for example, could result in errors or other file corruption, and even purely informational output might be mixed from multiple threads or reflect inconsistent changing state. See [Gensim's open bug report #2181 for more details](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2182). It's possible the `on_batch` callbacks are removed entirely due to this risk in an upcoming release.

So I'd recommend adapting your code to use some other approach – perhaps the `on_epoch` callbacks? – instead. What operation did you want to do in such frequent/simultaneous worker-thread callbacks?

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! I’m interested in using Gensim word vectors for a research project where it is important to insert training on a secondary task, interspersed with training on the main objective. It would be nice to be able to do this at a smaller granularity than epoch. Do you have any suggestions? Gensim is our current target training architecture since it is so fast to train with sufficient threads.

Comment: You could perhaps interleave a full epoch of your alternate goal at the end of each standard epoch, or extend the Gensim source to apply your alternate goal per batch, or even for each micro-example. I'd suggest building on the prerelease `gensim-4.0.0beta` or github project `develop` branch source for any extensions. (The trickiest part to extend/change is in the essential cython-optimized code, which is quite a bit more fragile with respect to memory/threading, & relies on explicit cython-to-c(pp) then c(pp) compilation.)